# Passing the same Android surfaceview to C++ code via jni results in different values

Tags: java, android, c++

```
//Android
SurfaceView SW;

function doSomthing()
{
    startPreview(SW);
    snapShot(SW);
}

//C++
startPreview(jobject window)
{
    TDebug("w1 = %u",window);
}

snapshot(jobject window)
{
    TDebug("w2 = %u",window);
}
```

parameter conversion process as follows.

```
SurfaceView ->Object->Jobject(jni)->void*（C++）
```

why does `w1 != w2`?

---

> All JNI methods accept both local and global references as arguments. It's possible for references to the same object to have different values. For example, the return values from consecutive calls to NewGlobalRef on the same object may be different. To see if two references refer to the same object, you must use the IsSameObject function. Never compare references with == in native code.
>
> One consequence of this is that you must not assume object references are constant or unique in native code. The 32-bit value representing an object may be different from one invocation of a method to the next, and it's possible ?that two different objects could have the same 32-bit value on consecutive calls. Do not use jobject values as keys.

Comment: The parameters are reference counted handles to the underlying Java object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `jobject window` is a [local reference](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html). If you want to compare two object references whether they point to the same object you have to use `JNIEnv*` and `IsSameObject` its member function

```
static jobject window1=nullptr;
static jobject window2=nullptr;

Java_your_prefix_class_startPreview(JNIEnv *env,jobject thiz,jobject window){
    window1=env->NewGlobalRef(window);
}

Java_your_prefix_class_snapshot(JNIEnv *env,jobject thiz,jobject window){
    window2=env->NewGlobalRef(window);

    TDebug("windows are equal = %d", env->IsSameObject(window1, window2));
}
```

[More](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

I faced this problem not too far ago. `jobject`s passed to JNI functions can have different values even they point to same objects. It happens because JVM has some kind of local objects pool and every tick it clears all local objects to GC if they have no global references. **So if you want to store a pointer to jobject in your C++ code you have to create a global reference from a local one.** And please don't forget to release it with `env->DeleteGlobalRef` once you've done with your object or your program will have memory leaks otherwise.

Comment: I have several windows view window1, view window2 view Window3 etc.  and i need to compare the window passed by snapshot function to these view windows. Does this means i have to create an array of global references of all my views?

Comment: @lihu yes. Cause if you will access saved local pointer in next "tick" you will receive s runtime error

Comment: I used the same global reference in jni function startPreview() and snapshot()，but i still get different point values in C++ code.

Comment: @lihu it's ok. Check it with 'IsSameObject' function

Comment: I used IsSameObject function in jni.  passed the same global reference window A in jni function like  jniStartPreview(A) & jniSnapshot(A), but i still get different jobject values in C++ function. Do i need to use IsSameObject function in C++ code, then i should pass JNIEnv to C++ code too, how should i do this?

Comment: @lihu yes you have to pass JNIEnv everywhere in C++ code if you want JVM functionality in C++. I know this is not comfortable but there is [no other way](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html). I faced same issue several moths ago and I created class that stores  `std::map<std::thread::thread_id,JNIEnv*>` and allows accessing it from every where and I passed JNIEnv* into it once JNI call happens. If you're interested I can consult you about it in skype `fnc1234` or e-mail

Comment: I do have access to  JNIEnv* and jobject  In C++ code now, but  i face a new problem, i can't use jobject values as keys. Is there any jobject attributes i can use in my map to identify a jobject? and how can i get it?

Comment: @lihu you can use `jobjects` as keys if these `jobjects` are global references. Then you can compare it using `IsSameObject` `JNIEnv` function. If you need to use `std::map::find` with it it is better to have your java classes to inherit something with `int id` and pass this id to c++ and store this id as key in your map

Comment: when i put global ref 'jobj' in my map like 'm_map[jobj] = tempID' in a c++ function. I was confused about which type of my 'jobj' should be. static ? that results in so many static jobjects, and each one should have a unique name. Temp object? if the function ends, the 'jobj' will be released. Actually i don't know when i put a global ref into a map, which type of copy happens?

Comment: @lihu tell me please what your `jobjects` actually are and why do you need them in your `c++` code?